# I am have an error in Manifest AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

PC\AndroidStudioProjects\TabLayout\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:12: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.example.tablayout:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 17):

when you create your image assets make sure you choose debug mode or release mode. **So make it a release mode** and create your icon asset [image]

Comment: saved my day.
android studio is really stupid that checked debug option as a default  option

Comment: this works, we can choose main or release to generate icon

Comment: could you please mention the version of android studio you're using

Comment: The latest one as of now 2022.2.1

Answer (score 6):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` and find property `android:roundIcon`. Then remove this line, it's optional.

In case if you need `android:roundIcon`, just create it with in-IDE tools (right-mouse-click on `resources` directory, then "New" -> "Image Asset")

Comment: I am solving this error but when I clicked make pro apeared this  AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.TabLayout (aka com.example.tab layout:style/Theme.TabLayout) not found

Comment: this works, additionally I recreated icon in Main mode

Answer (score -2):

Android build failed due to mipmap/launcher_icon missing or path change. without launcher_icon app not install . drag and drop app icon to mipmap & re-run ur app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).