# When executing the command npm run android --emulator, throws an error Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, vue.js, cordova

I'm trying to build a vue.js app with cordova but I don't know if there are versioning errors between android sdk, or gradle and I don't know how to configure it, the errors it throws me are these:

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:D:\Integrity\REPOS\MASTER\clientApp\src-cordova\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:46: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.integrity.seguros.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
44 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 42 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\Integrity\REPOS\MASTER\clientApp\src-cordova\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Integrity\REPOS\MASTER\clientApp\src-cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle

I attach an image of the problem

[error image terminal vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6retO.png)

I tried installing the latest version of android with the following sdk tools

[sdk tools installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT9wR.png)

Then I tried deleting the platform folder and creating it again with the following command:

cordova add platform android

and then when I run: cordova run android --emulator, it throws this error

also create the virtual device here

[virtual device android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHsYG.png)

Comment: it seems that there is a missing drawable .. make sure to have the missing drawable of rounded icon  **error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.integrity.seguros.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_round)** check this link may help also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626808/i-am-have-an-error-in-manifest-aapt-error-resource-mipmap-ic-launcher-round-no]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.